Convert a char* to a jByteArray or do a Latin1 to UFT8 conversion
In order to transfer data from a PLC to my application, I have a C/C++ API from the PLC manufacturer. Since my application is written in Java I use SWIG to get access to the API.
This is an extract of my interface file. Everything is working almost as expected and I can read the PLC variables from my Java application.
%inline %{
  typedef struct {
    PlcVarValue **ppChangedValues;
  } SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue;
%}

%typemap(in) PlcVarValue ***OUTVALUE {
  jclass clazz = jenv->FindClass("companyName/departmentName/productName/plchandler/swig/SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue");
  jfieldID fid = jenv->GetFieldID(clazz, "swigCPtr", "J");
  jlong cPtr = jenv->GetLongField($input, fid);
  SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue *pSwigPara_pppPlcVarValue = NULL;
  *(SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue **)&pSwigPara_pppPlcVarValue = *(SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue **)&cPtr;
  $1 = &pSwigPara_pppPlcVarValue->ppChangedValues;
}

%typemap(jtype) PlcVarValue ***OUTVALUE "SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue"
%typemap(jstype) PlcVarValue ***OUTVALUE "SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue"
%typemap(jni) PlcVarValue ***OUTVALUE "jobject"
%typemap(javain) PlcVarValue ***OUTVALUE "$javainput"

%apply PlcVarValue ***OUTVALUE { PlcVarValue ***pppChangedValues, PlcVarValue ***pppValues };

%extend SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue {
  PlcVarValue* getVar(long index) {return self->ppChangedValues[index]; }
  bool getQuality(long index) {return self->ppChangedValues[index]->bQuality; }
  unsigned long getTimeStamp(long index) {return self->ppChangedValues[index]->ulTimeStamp; }
  char* getString(long index) { return (char*)&(self->ppChangedValues[index]->byData); }
  int getInt(long index) {return *(int*)self->ppChangedValues[index]->byData; }
  long long getLong(long index) {return *(long long*)self->ppChangedValues[index]->byData; }
  double getDouble(long index) {return *(double*)self->ppChangedValues[index]->byData; }
  float getFloat(long index) {return *(float*)self->ppChangedValues[index]->byData; }
  unsigned char getByte(long index) {return self->ppChangedValues[index]->byData[0]; }
  unsigned char* getData(long index, int size) {return &self->ppChangedValues[index]->byData[0]; }
};

There is only one issue with the getString function. When the string in the PLC contains special characters like "²" then the string is not displayed correctly in my Java application (encoding problem).
The PLC sends the string in latin 1 encoding (ISO8859-1). This means every characters is represented by one byte. However, the generated C function creates a UTF8 encoded string. For "normal" characters UTF8 and latin 1 are compatible. But "special" characters need more bytes in UTF8 encoding and then they are no longer compatible.
This is the generated C function using the internal getString function.
SWIGEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_companyName_departmentName_productName_plchandler_swig_PLCHandlerJNI_SwigPara_1pppPlcVarValue_1getString(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg1, jobject jarg1_, jint jarg2) {
  jstring jresult = 0 ;
  SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue *arg1 = (SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue *) 0 ;
  long arg2 ;
  char *result = 0 ;
  
  (void)jenv;
  (void)jcls;
  (void)jarg1_;
  arg1 = *(SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue **)&jarg1; 
  arg2 = (long)jarg2; 
  result = (char *)SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue_getString(arg1,arg2);
  if (result) jresult = jenv->NewStringUTF((const char *)result);
  return jresult;
}

I tried two approaches.

The extended function SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue_getString should do itself a conversion from latin 1 to UTF8 (1-4 bytes per character) but then I had the issue that I had to allocate memory inside the function and I do not know how the interface file must look like, that the memory is freed again.
I tried to use typemaps to convert a char* to a jByteArray. But this typemap should only be applied to the getString function. A have multiple other functions with char* return value and they should remain as they are.

I did some research and tried multiple examples. But I did not manage to get a running solution in my context.
I think these two links describe parts of my problem:
How do I apply a SWIG typemap to _only_ a specific function?
Swig: convert return type std::string(binary) to java byte[]
How can I solve this issue?
I'm using swigwin-4.1.1.

Is it an option to change the return type of the getString function in your %extend block to a dummy type that you can then typemap?

Yes that would be possible. But then it would be great if you can help me somehow.

Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share how exactly are displayed special characters like "²"? Please (if possible) show us more complex string instead the only particular character ² (U+00B2,  Superscript Two).

Typical strings I want to transmit are e.g. units like mm/s² or just ordinary strings like "This is a error message. Error code: 0123456".

This is why I never use SWIG - to do anything hard, you need to learn the intricacies of both SWIG and JNI.  And when you throw in the fact that SWIG-generated code isn't robust, IMO it's just not worth it.  (Oh no it's not robust at all - SWIG creates no error checking for generated code such as jclass clazz = jenv->FindClass();.  It just blindly assumes it works, and if the call doesn't actually succeed, continuing like that corrupts the JVM.  And if you look closely at the generated code, there's usually quite a bit of undefined behavior in it...)

Good update! Post that as a self-answer instead.

I have now found a working solution for me. I have added the %newobject attribute for getString. By doing this swig knows that the return value of getString is a pointer to allocated memory and deletes that memory after copying the string. At least I hope that.
%newobject getString;
char* getString(long index) {
    // This string is latin1 encoded (check codesys documentation) 1 byte per character
    char* latin1_str = (char*)&(self->ppChangedValues[index]->byData);
    size_t latin1_len = strlen(latin1_str);

    // Allocate a buffer for the UTF-8 string (maximum 2 bytes per Latin1 character)
    size_t utf8_max_len = 2 * latin1_len;
    char* utf8_str = new char[utf8_max_len + 1]; // +1 for the null terminator
    if (!utf8_str) {
        return nullptr; // Memory allocation failed
    }

    // Convert Latin1 to UTF-8
    char* utf8_ptr = utf8_str;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < latin1_len; i++) {
        // Add the 1 or 2 bytes of the utf8 encoding to the utf8_str by using the utf8_ptr
        // Increase the pointer by 1 or 2
        utf8_ptr += latin1_to_utf8((unsigned char)latin1_str[i], utf8_ptr);
    }

    // Null-terminate the UTF-8 string
    *utf8_ptr = '\0';

    return utf8_str;
  }

The extract of the c function that results is
{
  arg1 = *(SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue **)&jarg1; 
  arg2 = (long)jarg2; 
  result = (char *)SwigPara_pppPlcVarValue_getString(arg1,arg2);
  if (result) jresult = jenv->NewStringUTF((const char *)result);
  delete [] result;
  return jresult;
}

I assume that delete [] result does complete free the allocated memory allocated with new. Also if for my string not the complete memory is used because some characters only need 1 byte in the UTF8 representation.
